# cannot find redirect code for open cart permissions

Tags: opencart

In OpenCart if user doesn't have permission to access the controller an error page shows up. When user logs in it determines which user permission the user has.

**Question**: I would like to know how does it redirect in this case? I know where the controller is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any route that's executed/dispatched is done so with an `Action`. So by default the `index.php` uses

```
// Router
if (isset($request->get['route'])) {
    $action = new Action($request->get['route']);
} else {
    $action = new Action('common/home');
}
```

which determines if you need to load a route if the `route` GET parameter is set, or the `common/home` if none is set (ie when the domain is just `http://yoursite.com/` instead of `http://www.yoursite.com/index.php?route=common/home`)

Similarly, when permission isn't granted, the action will render the `error/permission` route when it's invalid. This is checked in `/admin/controller/error/permission.php` in this code specifically (OC V2.0.0.0b)

```
if (!in_array($route, $ignore) && !$this->user->hasPermission('access', $route)) {
    return new Action('error/permission');
}
```

If you want to learn more on how it works under the hood, you can take a look at `/system/engine/action.php`